# The obstacle does not keep spawning. Only one spawns initially then the loop is cut off?

Tags: python, scroll, pygame

The code is not generating the object at the timer I set it at.

```
pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT+2, random.randrange(10, 500))
obstacles = obstacles(1050,300,64,64)

while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT+2:
            objects.append(obstacles)

            for object1 in objects:
                object1.x -= 1
                if object1.x < -100:
                    objects.pop(objects.index(object1))
```

No error message, however only one obstacle appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is to `.append` the same object again and again.

> ```
> objects.append(obstacles)
> ```

Delete the line:

> <s>`obstacles = obstacles(1050,300,64,64)`</s>

This doesn't do what you expect. `obstacles` is a class, but after that `obstacles` is an object of the former class `obstacles`.

When an new obstacle should spawn,then you've to `.append` a new `obstacles` object:

```py
if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT+2:
    new_obstacle = obstacles(1050,300,64,64)
    objects.append(new_obstacle )
```

Note, in the snippet the object (`new_obstacle`) has a different name then the class (`obstacles`) and a new object is constructed each time.